# Run Time error 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I can't for the life of my figure out why I'm getting "'Range' of object'_global' failed".

Below is the highlighted code in the debugger:

```
Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow + Data1ColumnDTotalRows - 2)
```

Note, I need the - 2 at the end of the formula to stay because this essentially copies and paste data, the reason it is suddenly breaking is because the whole page is blank which can sometimes happen in this big data dump. The - 2 is there because I’ve run into an issue where when 2 numbers or less were there the VBA at the end was doubling.

Full VBA Code:

​

```
Sub FirstClick()

​

Sheets("combined sheet").Activate

Range("A2:D100000").Clear

Dim Data1ColumnD, Data2ColumnF, Data3ColumnD, Data4ColumnD, PivotTablePasteRange As Range

Dim Data1ColumnDLastRow, Data1ColumnDTotalRows, Data2ColumnFLastRow, Data2ColumnFTotalRows,Data3ColumnDLastRow, Data3ColumnDTotalRows,
Data4ColumnDLastRow, Data4ColumnDTotalRows, LastRow AsLong

Sheets("Data1").Activate

Data1ColumnDLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data1ColumnDTotalRows = Data1ColumnDLastRow - 1

Set Data1ColumnD = Range("D4:D" & Data1ColumnDLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data2").Activate

Data2ColumnFLastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data2ColumnFTotalRows = Data2ColumnFLastRow - 1

Set Data2ColumnF = Range("F2:F" & Data2ColumnFLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data3").Activate

Data3ColumnDLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data3ColumnDTotalRows = Data3ColumnDLastRow - 1

Set Data3ColumnD = Range("D2:D" & Data3ColumnDLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data4").Activate

Data4ColumnDLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data4ColumnDTotalRows = Data4ColumnDLastRow - 1

Set Data4ColumnD = Range("D2:D" & Data4ColumnDLastRow)

​

Sheets("combined sheet").Activate

​

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

**Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow + Data1ColumnDTotalRows - 2)**

Data1ColumnD.Copy

If Data1ColumnDTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow + Data2ColumnFTotalRows)

Data2ColumnF.Copy

If Data2ColumnFTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow + Data3ColumnDTotalRows)

Data3ColumnD.Copy

If Data3ColumnDTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "B" & LastRow + Data4ColumnDTotalRows)

Data4ColumnD.Copy

If (Data4ColumnDTotalRows > 0) Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

Dim Data1ColumnH, Data2ColumnJ, Data3ColumnM, Data4ColumnM, PivotTableColumnBPasteRange,Data4Columnoutput As Range

Dim Data1ColumnHLastRow, Data1ColumnHTotalRows, Data2ColumnJLastRow, Data2ColumnJTotalRows,Data3ColumnMLastRow, Data3ColumnMTotalRows,
Data4ColumnMLastRow, Data4ColumnMTotalRows,Data4ColumnCoutputRows As Long

​

Sheets("Data1").Activate

Data1ColumnHLastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data1ColumnHTotalRows = Data1ColumnHLastRow - 1

Set Data1ColumnH = Range("H4:H" & Data1ColumnHLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data2").Activate

Data2ColumnJLastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data2ColumnJTotalRows = Data2ColumnJLastRow - 1

Set Data2ColumnJ = Range("J2:J" & Data2ColumnJLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data3").Activate

Data3ColumnMLastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data3ColumnMTotalRows = Data3ColumnMLastRow - 1

Set Data3ColumnM = Range("M2:M" & Data3ColumnMLastRow)

​

Sheets("Data4").Activate

Data4ColumnMLastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Data4ColumnMTotalRows = Data4ColumnMLastRow - 1

Set Data4ColumnM = Range("M2:M" & Data4ColumnMLastRow)

​

Sheets("combined sheet").Activate

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "C" & LastRow + Data1ColumnHTotalRows - 2)

Data1ColumnH.Copy

If Data1ColumnHTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "C" & LastRow + Data2ColumnJTotalRows)

Data2ColumnJ.Copy

If Data2ColumnJTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "C" & LastRow + Data3ColumnMTotalRows)

Data3ColumnM.Copy

If Data3ColumnMTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("C" & LastRow + 1 & ":" & "C" & LastRow + Data4ColumnMTotalRows)

Data4ColumnM.Copy

If Data4ColumnMTotalRows > 0 Then

PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

​

Dim MyRange As Long

MyRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim src As String

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Mapping")

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

src = "R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & lastColumn

Range("D2:D" & MyRange).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Mapping!" & src & ",2,0), ""Not Mapped"")"

​

​

Application.CutCopyMode = False

​

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

​

Range("A2").Select

​

End Sub

​
```

Comment: You only need the top-left cell of a paste range.

Comment: apologize, I'm not following

Answer (score 0):

You only need the top-left cell of a paste range.

```
...
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set PivotTablePasteRange = Range("B" & LastRow + 1)

If Data1ColumnDTotalRows > 0 Then

    Data1ColumnD.Copy
    PivotTablePasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If
...
```